# Jointjs with TogetherJs

Tags: javascript, collaboration, jointjs, diagramming, togetherjs

I am planning  of developing a web based application that would allow people to draw architectural diagrams and I want to give it the functionality of collaborating. If one user makes some changes the other could see and also make further changes if needed in real-time.

I researched and found that [Jointjs](http://jointjs.com) and [Togetherjs](https://togetherjs.com), if worked together can do the trick. I tried looking for integration ideas online but was unable to.

Has anybody tried using both of these together? Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying through these two libraries?

Any leads would be really appreciated.

Comment: Rappid has this functionality. Have a look at http://jointjs.com/rappid/docs/com/channel

Comment: @Thirumal   Hi, I am aware of Rappid but that is a paid application. I want to build something open source thus am not willing to pay for the plugins that they are providing